# QuickBlox - Same User Login From Different Locations/Devices

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, quickblox

User1: Login from multiple devices

User2: Call User1

All devices of User1 get the call notification. When one of the devices accept the call, other devices don't get any notification about that. How we can handle this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

on all three platforms it can be realized the following way:

(Example for iOS)
http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Chat_in_1-1_private_dialog

Send an info about drawing points each 1 second for example via chat messages 
like

```
QBChatMessage *message = [QBChatMessage message];
[message setText:@"Hey there"];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
params[@"x"] = @(22);
params[@"y"] = @(32);

[message setCustomParameters:params];
[privateChatDialog sendMessage:message];
```